# JQuery. Copy link attribute to a dynamic element within a div

Tags: jquery, append, href, attr

I'm still learnig jQuery and I'm stuck trying to have each of the dynamically generated links the same URL as the previous static link within the Div. The code seems to apply the same URL (#1) to all the generated links, when on the second Div I need it to be #2.

CODE:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.sorter > div p').append('<a class="rdm">Read More</a>');
$('a.rdm').each(function() {
    var lnk = $('.sorter > div').find('a').attr('href');
    $(this).attr('href', '' + lnk);
});
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="sorter">
<div><a href="#1">link A</a><p>some text </p></div><br /><br />
<div><a href="#2">link B</a><p>some text </p></div>
</div>
```

Many thanks for your help!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Oh i think you need this one: http://jsfiddle.net/GSgz5/

```
 var lnk = $(this).parent().siblings('a').attr('href'); //<--get href this way
 $(this).attr('href', lnk);
```

Comment: have you gone through the fiddle link.

Comment: actually gives me an undefined#1 target

Comment: not this one see the updated var lnk in this answer and the fiddle link.

Answer (score 2):

Using scoped selectors helps you deal with each div individually. Here's a jsfiddle with a working solution: http://jsfiddle.net/tuAUb/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.sorter > div').each(function() {
        $('p', this).append('<a class="rdm">Read More</a>');
        var lnk = $(this).find('a').attr('href');
        $('a.rdm', this).attr('href', lnk);
    });
});
```

Comment: shure it did! :) I'm still a long way to fully grasp how JQ works and help like this is invaluable. you can see it at work here http://columbusecuador.com/elt/

Answer (score 0):

Try this.  When you do the `each` I use the index of the anchor to generate it's `href`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.sorter > div p').append('<a class="rdm">Read More</a>');
    $('a.rdm').each(function(i) {
        $(this).attr('href', '#' + (i + 1));
    });
});
```